# read gen2 secondary account with databricks

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-storage-account

I'm trying to read the secondary gen2 account in DataBricks, but I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Operation failed: &#34;The specified resource does not exist.&#34;, 404
```

follow the way I'm making the connection:

```
spark.conf.set(
"fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-secondary>.dfs.core.windows.net",
"acess_key")
```

What is the correct way to log into a gen2 secondary account?

Answer (score 0):

You can access gen2 account databricks based on the following configuration .

```
spark.conf.set(
"fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net",
dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope-name>",key="<storage-account-access-key-name>"))
```

You can refer [here](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-get-started.html).

NOTE : Accessing any storage container through access key is highly  not recommended.

Comment: Could you expend on why it is not and how it can be accessed?